# Autogen guid (*) in Windowsinstaller cause ICE08 error

Tags: windows, build, installation, wix, windows-installer

Two component tags in my wxs file is as folllows

```
<Component Id="Comp.Comp1" Guid="*" >
<Condition><![CDATA[VersionNT < 602]]></Condition>
<File Id="File1" Source="$(Dir1)\TestFile.dll" />
 </Component>

<Component Id="Comp.Comp2" Guid="*" >
<Condition><![CDATA[VersionNT >= 602]]></Condition>
<File Id="File2" Source="$(Dir2)\TestFile.dll" />
 </Component>
```

But iam getting an error as below

```
ICE08: Component: Comp.Comp2 has a duplicate GUID: {2963D8E7-CBEC-50C8-AF4B-65E895FE3283}
```

How iam getting this error eventhough i gave an autogen guid value "*"

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The star-GUID for `Component` elements calculates a stable GUID based on the target location of the file. The **stability** of the GUID is vital for future updates (particularly patching). It works great in many cases but mutually exclusive Components that put a file into the exact same location is not one. In this case, you'll need to explicitly set at least one of your `Component/@Guid`s.

In the above case, you can do the following:

```
<Component Id="Comp.Comp1" Guid="*" >
    <Condition><![CDATA[VersionNT < 602]]></Condition>

    <File Id="File1" Source="$(Dir1)\TestFile.dll" />
</Component>

<Component Id="Comp.Comp2" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <Condition><![CDATA[VersionNT >= 602]]></Condition>

    <File Id="File2" Source="$(Dir2)\TestFile.dll" />
</Component>
```

Technically speaking you could suppress the ICE08 error in this case because the Components are mutually exclusive but I, personally, would do the above before suppressing the ICE. IMHO, it is preferable that the different files have different GUIDs ultimately anyway.

Comment: You'll still get warnings though saying the same file gets installed on SFN and LFN systems.

Comment: Very true, but IIRC those warnings explicitly state that it's okay if the Components are mutually exclusive. Since these are mutually exclusive, the warning can be acknowledged and ignored (although I wish we had the mechanism to acknowledge it in code and suppress it, be a nice feature one day).

Comment: I understand.  My perspective is working on very, very large projects ( Visual Studio Product Line complexity ) where there was so much code that it was a challenge to automate knowing what to ignore and what not to ignore.  Therefore we went to extremes to decrease the warnings.

Comment: Yeah, I know that feeling. Again, a feature in WiX toolset to acknowledge warnings would be great. But ICEs need lots of work so we'll see if something comes in the future.

Comment: Hi chris and Rob,
I have one more issue Will this above condition work in 64 bit OS?
If not then how can i give the new condition.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you Rob,
Rob i tried by suppersing the ICE08 error.Eventhought the installtion went well the uninstallation leaves the above file in the ProgramFile folder.So i tried by putting a GUID for one of the component.It uninstall the component without leaving any files and my issue solved.Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: If the file was left behind, that likely means another Product on the machine was still holding a reference to the Component. A verbose log would be necessary to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the context of this snippet ( Directory Elements)  but to me it seems you are installing the same filename to the same directory twice.  That's a component rule violation.  The "source" is different but the conditions are the same : !VersionNT >= 602.

Comment: ohh sorry i have changed the condition.
can i suppress ICE08 error

Comment: I think I've read Rob say you can but I wouldn't.  The reason is even though the file name is the same, they are not compatible components.  First I'd ask if you can redesign your software to use different filenames (an example is a factory that selects the correct O/S specific implementation).  From an installer perspective what I do is I install these files as different filenames and/or directories ( therefore different GUIDs)  then use the CopyFile element to get them duplicated to the correct directory / filename.

Comment: Eventhough the filenames are same the files are different.One file is under .net3.5 and one under .net4.And i can't give different name for the filenames

Comment: But you can install them to subdirectories [INSTALLDIR]A\TestFile.dll and [INSTALLDIR]B\TestFile.dll and then use CopyFile elements to copy [INSTALLDIR]X\TestFile.dll to [INSTALLDIR]TestFile.dll.  The downside is you'll have the DLL installed once. One that matters and one that doesn't.  The upside is you'll be able to easily identify *which* file got installed and you'll pass ICE validations.

Comment: It is a good tip Chris and it works.Thanks for your valuable time