# Component rules problem: Installing version-dependent plugin files alongside an existing application

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am writing the Wix installer for a plugin for a 3rd party application (I will call the 3rd party app `Foo` here). I do not control the 3rd party application, and must work with the requirements it dictates. The plugin (a dll) must be installed to a specific directory inside the 3rd party application's installation (eg, `C:\Program Files\Foo\bin`). There are several versions of the plugin dll that have binary compatibility with specific versions of `Foo`, and my installer must check the installed version of `Foo` and install the correct plugin dll to match. `Foo` also requires that the plugin dll must have the same filename regardless of the version installed.

I have custom actions that detect the installed version and installation location of `Foo` - this is not the problem.

The problem is: What is the correct/best/least-worst way to approach this problem as regards component GUIDs etc (ie, the [Component Rules](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2003/10/18/component-rules-101/)), and the multiple versions of my plugin DLL that might need to be installed (or might already be installed in an upgrade scenario), all of which have the exact same filename and must be installed to the exact same path?

Comment: Can there only be a single version of Foo installed at any given time or can there be multiple versions installed in different directories?

Comment: @zett42 There can only be a single version of Foo installed.

Comment: [In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16172446/7571258), Rob Mensching indirectly states that mutually exclusive components which put a file into the exact same place, should have different GUIDs (complying to ICE08). Actually I think this breaks the components rules. So to avoid update issues, I would only use Major Upgrades (no patches) with scheduling of `afterInstallValidate`. With other scheduling, you could end up with the DLL removed after an upgrade (because reference counting could be broken due to different GUIDs).

Comment: Interestingly, [if all components with same GUIDs have conditions, then ICE08 is only issued as a warning, instead of an error](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/ICE08-changed-to-linker-error-in-3-6-tp7579846p7579850.html). So this means you can go with the IMO more correct way of using the same GUIDs and just suppress ICE08 (`light.exe -sice:ICE08`).

Comment: Some useful comments there. As it stands, the components are automatically harvested into different component groups, those groups are included in mutually-exclusive per-version features, and the features have conditions to ensure that only one feature is installed. While it's not impossible to apply conditions to the harvested components (using post-harvest XSL transform), it's certainly quite awkward. If I went with the duplicate GUIDs and component conditions, I wonder what would happen when doing a repair if the 3rd party app was upgraded since initial install of the plugin?

Comment: Good question. You would have to set the component attribute `Transitive="yes"` to make sure component conditions will be reevaluated during repair. This would cause the old version of the DLL to be uninstalled before the new version would be installed. I'm not even sure if this use case would work with feature conditions only as there is no "Transitive" flag for features.

Comment: According to "[Using Transitive Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/using-transitive-components)", it is required that *"Each transitive component must have its own unique GUID"*. This confirms Rob Menschings statement and invalidates my 2nd comment.

Comment: Another link from Installshield: [Reevaluating Component Conditions During Reinstallation](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpCompReevaluate.htm). Seems to capture your use case when replacing "OS version" by "version of Foo".

Comment: Following all the excellent comments from @zett42, using components with unique GUIDs, `Transitive="yes"`, and mutually-exclusive conditions seems to be the way to go, and it's working for me. @zett42 - if you would like to formulate this as an answer, I'll happily select it.

Comment: I have never tried to do something like this, so you are actually more experienced in this than me now. I suggest that you self-answer.